# Match a mysql stored REGEX

Tags: mysql

Here is the initial problem. We have a `redirections` table:

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+
| id |     uri     |      redirection       | code |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+
|  1 | ^/foo$      | https://www.google.com |  301 |
|  2 | ^/bar[0-9]$ | https://facebook.com   |  301 |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+
```

Now, I'm looking to make a request with a URI and see if it matches any of the regex on this table. For example, if I look for `/foo` it would return the first line. If I look for `/bar5`, it would return the second line.

As far as my research went, it is the opposite behaviour of REGEXP that I am looking for. Is it even possible?

**The only solution I came with to solve the problem was to retrieve all the lines and test each regex against my string. But this comes with some performances problems on my PHP application... Is their a Mysql way of doing this?**

Comment: My head hurts just thinking about this. Did you look at prepared statements already?

Comment: I don't see how prepared statements would solve the problem, how could it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern in [`expr REGEXP pat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) does not need to be a constant, but can be your `uri` column:

```
select * from redirections where '/bar5' regexp uri;
```

It will have to check every row, as it is obviously not possible to calculate *the* pattern by looking at the matching string.

Comment: Thank you, it works great, performances are indeed not that great as soon as the table contains a lot of lines